# How to export select statement data to excel using PLSQL method

Tags: plsql

I need to export below select statement into excel sheet using PLSQL with sysdate file name

```
"select * from( SELECT   
  ACPROJ.ACCOUNT_NAME CUSTOMER_NAME,  
  CUST.NAME ACCOUNT_NAME,  
  PRJ.SEGMENT1 PROJECT_NUM,  
  PRJ.NAME PROJECT_NAME,  
  PPF.FULL_NAME EMPLOYEE_FULL_NAME,  
  PPF.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,  
  PPARTY.PROJECT_ROLE_MEANING PROJECT_ROLE,   
  PROJTIER.PROJECT_ROLE_TIER,   
  TR.NAME AS DESIGNATION,  
  TR.ATTRIBUTE1 AS TIER,  
  TR.SEGMENT2 AS CEG,  
  CURRATC.ATTRIBUTE1 CURRENT_ATC,   
  TO_CHAR(PPARTY.START_DATE_ACTIVE, 'DD-MON-YYYY') ALLOCATION_START_DATE,  
  TO_CHAR(PPARTY.END_DATE_ACTIVE, 'DD-MON-YYYY') ALLOCATION_END_DATE,  
  XPA.ALLOCATION_STATUS ALLOCATION_STATUS,  
  APPS.XXVIR_PA_REQUIREMENT_UTIL_PKG.GET_AVAIL_PCT(PCD.ASSIGNMENT_ID) ALLOCATED_PCT,  
  NVL(XPA.BILLABLE_PERCENTAGE,0)||'%' BILLABLE_PCT,  
  APPS.XXVIR_PA_REQUIREMENT_UTIL_PKG.GET_PROJECT_TYPE(PCD.PROJECT_ID) PROJECT_TYPE,  
  APPS.XXVIR_PA_REQUIREMENT_UTIL_PKG.GET_DELIVERY_CENTER(PCD.PROJECT_ID) DELIVERY_CENTER,  
  PPS_PR.PROJECT_STATUS_NAME      
  FROM APPS.PA_PROJECT_ASSIGNMENTS PCD;"
```

Comment: YOu mean you want to run that query and have the results written to an excel file? Take a look here - https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/generating-csv-files

Comment: Hello, please share what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

There's an XLSX reading/writing piece of PLSQL library on the Internet. Google for [Anton Scheffer's XLSX PLSQL](https://www.google.at/search?q=anton%20scheffer%20xlsx%20plsql). It's not a speed demon per se and is a heavy memory consumer, but works anyway, and can be neatly tuned up (with some notrivial effort).